# ¿Cómo compruebo la secuencia de las dos listas?(Processing)

Tags: java, array, game

Estoy intentando hacer el juego "Simon dice" , quiero comprobar la secuencia de las dos listas, listaAcertar e intentoUsuario, la listaAcertar seria algo asi int[] listaAcertar={c1,c2,c3,c4} siendo cada "c" un cuadrante, "cuadrante1, cuadrante2, etc.." y la lista de intentoUsuario seria si es correcto int[] intentoUsuario={c1,c2,c3,c4} y si es erronea int[] intentoUsuario={c2,c1,c4,c3} porque no coinciden y tocaria volver a empezar el juego de nuevo ¿que me falta? ¿Cómo lo hago? y después en caso de acierto ¿cómo aumento a mostrar en 1 mas la secuencia?¿Tengo algún error? c1,c2,c3,c4 son las funciones donde esta el color y tamaño de los cuadrantes.

```
class Listas{

int[] listaAcertar={};
int[] intentoUsuario={};
int n=0;

void mostrarSecuencia(){
if (listaAcertar[n]==0){
  background(0);
} else if (listaAcertar[n]==1) {
cuadrantes.c1();
} else if (listaAcertar[n]==2) {
cuadrantes.c2();
} else if (listaAcertar[n]==3) {
cuadrantes.c3();
} else if (listaAcertar[n]==4) {
cuadrantes.c4();
}
}

void mousePressed(){
if (mousePressed) {
  if (mouseX < width/2 && mouseY < height/2) {
    cuadrantes.c1();
    intentoUsuario=append(intentoUsuario,1);
  } else if(mouseX > width/2 && mouseY < height/2) {
    cuadrantes.c2();
    intentoUsuario=append(intentoUsuario,2);
  } else if(mouseX < width/2 && mouseY > height/2) {
    cuadrantes.c3();
    intentoUsuario=append(intentoUsuario,3);
  } else if(mouseX > width/2 && mouseY > height/2) {
    cuadrantes.c4();
    intentoUsuario=append(intentoUsuario,4);
  }
}
}

}
```

Esta es otra clase:

```
class Rondas{

final int mensajeUno = 1;
final int inicio = 2;
final int secuencia = 3;
final int mensajeDos = 4;
final int introSecuencia = 5;
final int comprobacion = 6;
final int casoFallo = 7;
final int casoAcierto = 8;
final int pregunta = 9;

int estado = mensajeUno;

void Inicio(){
switch (estado) {
  case mensajeUno:
  background(0);
  textSize(32);
  fill(255);
  text("EMPEZAMOS EL JUEGO...", 50, height/2);
  estado=inicio;
  break;
  //Generamos la primera secuancia
  case inicio:
  delay(1000);
  listas.listaAcertar=append(listas.listaAcertar, int(random(1, 4)));
  listas.listaAcertar=append(listas.listaAcertar, 0);
  estado=secuencia;
  //Enseñamos la secuencia al jugador
  case secuencia:
  if (listas.n<listas.listaAcertar.length) {
    listas.mostrarSecuencia();
    delay(1500);
    listas.n++;
  }else{
    estado=mensajeDos;
  }
  break;
  //Anunciamos que toca al jugador
  case mensajeDos:
  background(0);
  textSize(32);
  fill(255);
  text("Tú turno...", 50, height/2);
  estado=introSecuencia;
  break;
  case introSecuencia:
  if(listas.intentoUsuario.length<listas.listaAcertar.length){
  listas.mousePressed();
  }else{
  estado=comprobacion;
}
  break;
  case comprobacion:
  for (int i=0;i<listas.listaAcertar.length;i++) {
     i++;
      for (int j=0;j<listas.intentoUsuario.length;j++) {
        j++;
        if (listas.listaAcertar[i]==listas.intentoUsuario[j]) {
          estado=casoAcierto;
        }else{
          estado=casoFallo;
        }
      }
    }
  break;
  case casoAcierto:
  background(0);
  textSize(32);
  text("Has acertado", 50, height/2);
  estado=secuencia;
  break;
  case casoFallo:
  background(0);
  textSize(32);
  text("Has fallado", 50, height/2);
  estado=pregunta;
  break;
  case pregunta:
  delay(1000);
  background(0);
  textSize(32);
  text("Volver a empezar", 50, height/2);
  estado=inicio;
  break;
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Podrias tratar de poner un poco de contexto o un ejemplo a tu pregunta? yo veo mucho codigo y no entiendo que problema tenes

Comment: @gbianchi elproblema es aquí: 
  case comprobando:
  estado=comprobacion;
  break;
  case comprobacion:
  if(listas.listaAcertar==listas.intentoUsuario){
    estado=casoAcierto;
al comparar las listas, algo hago mal, porque al pulsar sobre el cuadro de la secuencia no es correcto.

Comment: @gbianchi ¿Entonces seria así? listas.listaAcertar.length==listas.intentoUsuario.length, aunque tambien probé asi e igual no funcionaba correctamente, ¿puede que el problema lo tenga en case introSecuencia y no en comprobar?

Comment: @gbianchi lo he intentado asi       if(listas.listaAcertar[listas.n]==listas.intentoUsuario[listas.n]){ pero me aparece arrayindexoutofboundsexception 2

Comment: @gbianchi "listas.n" es para llamar a "n" que esta en la clase Listas, tu dices crear dos "for" para recorrerlas, una para listaAcertar y otra para intentoUsuario y después poner algo asi if(listas.listaAcertar[i]==listas.intentoUsuario[j]) ¿es a lo que te refieres?

Comment: @gbianchi si, el problema es que me sigue dando como incorrecto cuando selecciono el mismo color que me indica la secuencia, es el juego "simon dice", la listaAcertar es la que va a mostrar la secuencia listas.listaAcertar=append(listas.listaAcertar, int(random(1, 4))) y la lista de intentoUsuario es la que se va a llenar con el cuadro de color que seleccione, para despues compararlas.

Comment: @gbianchi la lista acertar seria algo asi int[] listaAcertar={c1,c2,c3,c4} siendo cada "c" un cuadrante, "cuadrante1, cuadrante2, etc.." y la lista de intentoUsuario seria si es correcto int[] intentoUsuario={c1,c2,c3,c4} y si es erronea int[] intentoUsuario={c2,c1,c4,c3} porque no coinciden y tocaria volver a empezar el juego de nuevo, mostrar la secuencia y demás esta todo en el código que he puesto, no se si he cometido algun error en algún paso como el de "case introSecuencia" no lo se seguro.

Comment: @gbianchi Añadí la información que puse a tus preguntas de los comentarios, si crees que necesito añadir algo más, dimelo.

Answer (score 2):

Tu error es un error de logica.

Vos tenes dos vectores, y queres comparar que sean exactamente iguales.

En este caso es simple, porque los dos vectores son cortos.

Vos para comprobar escribiste lo siguiente:

```
for (int i=0;i<listas.listaAcertar.length;i++) {
    i++;
    for (int j=0;j<listas.intentoUsuario.length;j++) {
        j++;
        if (listas.listaAcertar[i]==listas.intentoUsuario[j]) {
            estado=casoAcierto;
        }else{
            estado=casoFallo;
        }
    }
}
```

Lo cual esta todo mal, ya que las variable i y j crecen por si mismas al iterar en el for, y para colmo estas comprobando todos los elementos de la lista acertar con todos los intentos de usuario, y como si fuera poco, tambien tambien por cada elemento estas poniendo la variable estado en uno u otro caso. Sin embargo, con todo esto codigo, lo unico que logras es que te diga si las dos ultimas posiciones son iguales, sin importar todo lo que paso en el medio.

En realidad todo esto se puede resolver de una forma mucho mas simple de esta forma:

```
if (listas.listaAcertar[0] == listas.intentoUsuario[0] &&        
    listas.listaAcertar[1] == listas.intentoUsuario[1] &&        
    listas.listaAcertar[2] == listas.intentoUsuario[2] &&        
    listas.listaAcertar[3] == listas.intentoUsuario[3]) {
        estado=casoAcierto;
    }else{
        estado=casoFallo;
    }
```

Otra forma seria meter todo en un for, y suponer que esta bien, y solo aclarar los casos que esten mal.. porque con un caso erroneo, ya esta todo mal.

```
estado=casoAcierto;
for (int j=0;j<listas.intentoUsuario.length;j++) {
    if (listas.listaAcertar[j]==listas.intentoUsuario[j]) {
      estado=casoFallo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya lo probé asi y me da error tambien, ya lo solucione yo solo de todas maneras, gracias. Y si, tengo algunos errores en el código, ya que voy probando si funciona o no, y voy aprendiendo. Ahora pongo como lo hice.

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione así:

Ya que la listAcertar contiene un 0 y al usar println veia que siempre aparecia un cero de más en la secuencia de listaAcertar, probe a poner -1 y se resolvio.

```
for (int i=0;i<listas.listaAcertar.length-1;i++){
     for (int j=0;j<listas.intentoUsuario.length;j++){
        if (listas.listaAcertar[i]==listas.intentoUsuario[j]){
          estado=casoAcierto;
        }else{
          estado=casoFallo;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Esto no puede funcionar nunca.. funciona solo si los dos ultimos elementos son iguales... si estan todos desordenados menos el ultimo de cada una te va a devolver que es un acierto y es falso

Comment: Yo lo llevo probando mucho tiempo y no me da ningún fallo, si selecciono la correcta es correcta y si selecciono error me da error, me va bien.

Comment: prueba poner toda la secuencia mal menos el ultimo

Comment: Así me aparece si pongo la lista sin el -1: i2 j2 i2 j2 i0 j2 i0 j2, son "i y j" todos igual menos los dos "i" finales, y dí la correcta, ahora como me aparece si selecciono tambien la correcta pero con el -1 puesto de nuevo: i2 j2 i2 j2 como ves, desaparecieron los ceros y las dos listas son iguales.

Comment: mejor ven al [chat]